# Partial Cell include in table Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of companies such as :

```
COCA
COCA COLA
SPRITE
```

An other list of companies is given, more detailled.

Is the cell a substring of at least one element of the list ?

```
COCA COLA USA    TRUE
PEPSI            FALSE
SPIRIT           FALSE
```

I have tried with approximate match but the result is wrong.
I would like something like this :

```
=EQUIV([@Company_long_name];"*"&Table[Company]&"*";0)
```

Thanks for reading

Comment: you could use an array-formula like `{=OR(ISNUMBER(IF(LEN(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$100),SEARCH(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$100,Sheet2!A1))))}` while in Sheet2!A1 is a Long string and in Sheet1!A1:A100 are the short ones...

Comment: and if you need it to be case sensitive, just replace `SEARCH`with `FIND` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

more than one way to do this, pick the one you are more comfortable with

[image]

method 1 formula

```
=SUM(IFERROR(MATCH("*"&($A$2:$A$4)&"*",$B2,0),0))>0
```

method 2 formula

```
=LARGE(COUNTIF(B2,"*"&$A$2:$A$4&"*"),1)>0
```

Note: this is array formula. it is not single array formula but seprate array for each cell. so first put formula into single cell (start at row 2 for my formula), then CTRL+D to to fill down.

Answer (score 1):

In VBA you could do something like this:

```
Sub findIfSubString()
   Dim ws1, ws2 As Worksheet

   Set ws1 = Worksheets("Tabelle1")
   Set ws2 = Worksheets("Tabelle2")

   i = 1


   Do While ws1.Cells(i, 1) <> ""

        j = 1
        ws2.Cells(i, 2) = "FALSE"
        Do While ws2.Cells(j, 1) <> ""
            If InStr(ws2.Cells(i, 1), ws1.Cells(i, 1)) Then
                ws2.Cells(i, 2) = "TRUE"
                Exit Do
            Else
                j = j + 1
            End If
        Loop
        i = i + 1
   Loop

End Sub
```

Change your code accordingly to your format. From your example, "COCA", "COCA COLA" and "SPRITE" would be in column 1 of `ws1` and both other set would be in columns 1 and 2 of `ws2`

EDIT:
Code looks now for possible in string-matches for all entries.

Comment: The two list can be in any order. I would prefer a formula, data will change

Comment: The long name as to be compared with all the short names